# Tridion SmartTarget : Error while publishing

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I am publishing a component to Fredhopper using the Add to SmartTarget TBB.
I am getting the following error in CD_Core log :

> 2015-11-02 16:04:12,325 DEBUG AbstractFredhopperDeployer - Calling
>   http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/config/smarttarget/runjob?job=STJob.kjb&instance=FredhopperIndexer&universe=catalog01to
>   start kettle job
>
> 2015-11-02 16:04:12,345 ERROR AbstractFredhopperDeployer - Unable to
>   start kettle job in Fredhopper ; Please check configuration and
>   Fredhopper Installation java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username
>   may not be null   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials.(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:90)
>   ~[commons-httpclient.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.AbstractFredhopperDeployer.triggerKettleJob(AbstractFredhopperDeployer.java:35)
>   ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.FileSystemDeployer.deploy(FileSystemDeployer.java:13)
>   [smarttarget_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.SmartTargetXMLUtils.persistFredhopperXML(SmartTargetXMLUtils.java:194)
>   [smarttarget_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperOutputBuilder.persistFredhopperXML(FredhopperOutputBuilder.java:119)
>   [smarttarget_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:76)
>   [smarttarget_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:116)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runSafeEvent(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:240)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:101)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
>   2015-11-02 16:04:12,347 WARN  CommitPhase - Failure during the
>   post-transaction and the transaction will NOT be rolled-back
>   2015-11-02 16:04:12,349 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to
>   execute onSuccess event in phase: Deployment Commit Phase for
>   transaction: tcm:0-8514-66560 2015-11-02 16:04:12,351 ERROR
>   DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction:
>   tcm:0-8514-66560 com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to
>   start kettle job in Fredhopper. Please check configuration and
>   Fredhopper Installation   at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.AbstractFredhopperDeployer.triggerKettleJob(AbstractFredhopperDeployer.java:58)
>   ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.FileSystemDeployer.deploy(FileSystemDeployer.java:13)
>   ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.SmartTargetXMLUtils.persistFredhopperXML(SmartTargetXMLUtils.java:194)
>   ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperOutputBuilder.persistFredhopperXML(FredhopperOutputBuilder.java:119)
>   ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:76)
>   ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:116)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runSafeEvent(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:240)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:101)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username may not be
>   null  at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials.(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:90)
>   ~[commons-httpclient.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.AbstractFredhopperDeployer.triggerKettleJob(AbstractFredhopperDeployer.java:35)
>   ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]    ... 17 common frames omitted

I am getting the component xml in the \data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01 folder.
Am I missing any configuration in fredhopper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am agree with Peter Answer for this issue. In SmartTarget configuration file it is required to configure IndexServer with credential required to authenticate. To avoid any confusion I am placing configuration snippets below:

```
<IndexServer>
    <!-- On premise Url -->
    <Url>http://localhost:8180/</Url>
   <Authentication>
        <!--Note that the username/password for the Deployment Webservice and Index Server are combined here -->
        <!--If you're on premise and have authentication enabled on the index server they need to be the same as for the Deployment Webservice -->
        <Username>admin</Username>
       <Password>encrypted:56StnjmsTNnHdITMkL4KYw==</Password>
    </Authentication>
    ...
</IndexServer>
```

You can put password as a plain text also. I hope configuring your smarttarget in this way will fix your issue..

Comment: Working after putting the credential in the config file.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the error message:

> Please check configuration and Fredhopper Installation
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Username may not be null**

So you need to add the right credentials to the SmartTarget configuration file, in the Fredhopper\IndexServer\Authentication section.